# Google Apps Script to automatically accept many pending file ownership transfer requests

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to automate acceptance of pending ownership requests for thousands of files on a Google Drive using Google Apps Script.

Here is my script.

```gas
function ownPendingFiles() {
  const OLD_OWNER1 = '[accountA]@gmail.com';
  const NEW_OWNER = '[accountB]@gmail.com';

  const QUERY = `"${OLD_OWNER1}" in owners and "${NEW_OWNER}" in writers` // query files owned by the sender and writable by the receiver

  var fileIter = DriveApp.searchFiles(QUERY); // return files matching the query
  const emailPermId = Drive.Permissions.getIdForEmail(NEW_OWNER).id; // get receiver's permission ID

  var fileList = []; // create an empty array for file IDs and information on pending ownership

  while (fileIter.hasNext()) { // for each file found, return its permissions
    var file = fileIter.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var filePermForEmail = Drive.Permissions.get(fileId, emailPermId); // get file permissions for receiver
    fileList.push([fileId,filePermForEmail.pendingOwner]); // write pending ownership information for files
  }

 var fileListToOwn = fileList.filter(file => file[1]===true); // select files with pending ownership requests
 var fileListToOwnIds = [];

 for(let i = 0, l = folderListToOwn.length; i < l; i++) { // create a list of file ids to own
   fileListToOwnIds.push(fileListToOwn[i][0]);
   var filesToOwn = DriveApp.getFileById(fileListToOwnIds[i]);
   Logger.log(filesToOwn.setOwner(NEW_OWNER))
 }
}
```

The script works well for a small number of requests, but fails for thousands, returning the 'Exceeded maximum execution time' error.

I am new to GAS and I could not implement workarounds for this problem reported elsewhere.

What would be a way to make the script work?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are reaching the total execution time as your code is currently looping over a thousand times, I would suggest checking how to [perform batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) in Apps script.

The specific part you can improve is this snippet of your code:

```
 for(let i = 0, l = folderListToOwn.length; i < l; i++) { // create a list of file ids to own
   fileListToOwnIds.push(fileListToOwn[i][0]);
   var filesToOwn = DriveApp.getFileById(fileListToOwnIds[i]);
   Logger.log(filesToOwn.setOwner(NEW_OWNER))
 }
```

In this portion of your code you are looping too many times over the `DriveApp.getFileById()` method thus you receive the maximum execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also thought about this snippet, but in fact some earlier code is responsible for the error (perhaps in addition to the snippet). I ran the code up to the 'while' loop, inserting `Logger.log(fileList.length)` after it, and it failed returning the same error.