# Auto-accept Ownership of a Google Sheet in GMail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

When you transfer ownership of a Google Sheet to another person, they get an email with an Accept button. I would like (as the receiving user) to auto accept ownership given a set of conditions. The conditions are the easy part, but I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to accept ownership programmatically.

I have been trying to use GAS to accomplish this ... but so far, nothing even close. My thoughts are a time-triggered script that looks through my email for a set of conditions. That is the easy part. The accept ownership is what has me stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Google Help has a brief section on [Accept or decline an ownership transfer request](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892?hl=en): `You can also search in Drive for files pending a response to an ownership transfer request.` The Drive API includes a `permissions`, `update`, method called `transferOwnership`. Might be a possibility.

Comment: Related question: [Google Apps Script to automatically accept many pending file ownership transfer requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74774246/1330560)

Comment: Is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75045027